# Populating List items in Java via Reflection

Tags: java, reflection

I have to populate object with values that are in String format and I have converter to convert String values to whatever values are required. But how can I know type of List items? Is it `List<String>` or `List<Integer>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on your use case, you can get the Generic type of a `List` via a few different methods.

[This post](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/generics.html) shows how it can be done for [return types](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/generics.html#returntypes) of methods, [parameters](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/generics.html#parametertypes) of methods, and [field variables](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/generics.html#fieldtypes)

> When runtime inspecting a
>   parameterizable type itself, like
>   java.util.List, there is no way of
>   knowing what type is has been
>   parameterized to. This makes sense
>   since the type can be parameterized to
>   all kinds of types in the same
>   application. But, when you inspect the
>   method or field that declares the use
>   of a parameterized type, you can see
>   at runtime what type the paramerizable
>   type was parameterized to.

If it's not one of these 3 cases, you cannot get the Generic type due to [type erasure](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html).

Answer (score 2):

Java generics are compile time features, List<String> and List<Integer> are same at runtime.. Therefore you can not know component type of a Collection at runtime..

This kind of question asked so many times, there is a way to get component type of Collection at runtime, but you can extend a collection class, while constructing it, you can give component class to the constructor, by this way you can get component type of collection at runtime.. Here is a sample ;

```
class GenericList<T> extends ArrayList<T> {
private Class<T> componentClasz;

public GenericList(Class<T> clasz){
    super();
    componentClasz = clasz;
}

public Class<T> getComponentClasz() {
    return componentClasz;
}
```

}

```
GenericList<String> list = new GenericList<String>(String.class);
```

Answer (score 1):

The type of the List was erased when the List was compiled.

Also, a String can't just be "converted" into any value willy-nilly.  For example of a conversion failure, what's the appropriate Integer value for "hello"?

If you want a list that can hold any Java object, use List<Object>.

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to examine the object(s) of the list, not the list itself.  Because Java uses type safe erasure and not reification there's no way to reflect the generic type of the list (or any other Java collection for that matter).